# Match exact pattern via re.search method only

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

How can I search exact word "dog" in below code? I know its syntax error

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
list = ["dog", "do", "dog-dumb", "no_match", "dogs"]
var2 = 'dog'

for i in list:
   match = re.search(^var2$, i)
   if match:
      print (match.group(0))
```

Error:

```
match = re.search(^var2$, i)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Regex should be a string. so `re.search('^var2$', i)`

Comment: Thanks. But after making the changes re.search('^var2$', i), I m not getting any output though the script executes without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search exact word `dog` then why bother using Regex? use simple equal operator

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
list = ["dog", "do", "dog-dumb", "no_match", "dogs"]
var2 = 'dog'

for i in list:
   if var2 == i:
      print (i)
```

If you want case-insensitive comparison then do

```
if var2.lower() == i.lower()
```

EDIT:

If you still insist on using regex, then do this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
list = ["dog", "dodog", "dog-dumb", "no_match", "dogs"]
var2 = 'dog'

for i in list:
  match = re.search("^"+var2+"$", i)
  if match:
    print (match.group(0))
```

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to achieve this via regex re.search method only?

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is exactly what I wanted.